# EntityManager ou Session? Qual usar?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Já trabalhei com projetos que utilizavam tanto Session quanto EntityManager mas nunca ficou claro qual devo escolher. No que me basear e em que eles se diferem em termos de performance e compatibilidade. Alguém pode dar uma dica ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O Hibernate surgiu primeiro, em 2001. Dentre os frameworks de mapeamento objeto-relacional que surgiram em Java, ele foi provavelmente o mais famoso, completo e bem sucedido. Ele utiliza o `Session`.

Entretanto, o Hibernate é um framework específico desenvolvido por um grupo específico. Em 2005, vários grupos se reuniram sob a coordenação da Sun para elaborar e estabelecer um padrão oficial para definir em termos genéricos o comportamento de frameworks de mapeamento objeto-relacional. Além disso, foi definido que esse framework utilizaria as características novas da linguagem do Java 5 (lançado em 2004), vez que nenhum framework objeto-relacional maduro as utilizava (tipos genéricos e anotações, principalmente). Os trabalhos foram bastante inspirados no Hibernate e houve bastante participação do pessoal do Hibernate. Disso nasceu o JPA em 2006. O JPA utiliza o `EntityManager`.

Um outro objetivo a ser atingido com a criação do JPA foi a eliminação do BMP e do CMP do EJB 2 (não deixarão saudades). Basicamente o CMP era uma tentativa de criar-se uma especificação de persistência e mapeamento objeto-relacional, mas era bastante complicado, difícil de se usar, fortemente acoplado ao EJB 2 e oferecia muito menos recursos que o Hibernate. O BMP era algo mais próximo ao que são os beans de entidade (anotados com `@Entity`) utilizados pelo JPA hoje, embora estivessem em um estado bem menos desenvolvido. Mas isso já é assunto para um outro tópico.

Quando o JPA finalmente nasceu, o Hibernate, obviamente passou a implementar o JPA, ganhando com isso adesão ao padrão oficial e também o uso de tipos genéricos e anotações. Ou seja, ele passou a reconhecer tudo o que o JPA reconhece. Nas primeiras versões do Hibernate com suporte ao JPA, o `EntityManager` redirecionava tudo o que ele fazia ao `Session`. Em versões mais novas do Hibernate (5.2+), isso é ainda mais simples porque a interface `Session` extende a interface `EntityManager` diretamente.

Porém, o Hibernate é apenas uma das implementações existentes do JPA (embora seja uma muito boa e seja a mais bem sucedida). Outras implementações do JPA surgiram. A saber:

- DataNucleus
- TopLink
- EclipseLink
- OpenJPA
- ObjectDB
- Orient DB
- Batoo JPA
- Kundera

De fato, a implementação de referência do JPA, ou seja, aquela que foi criada para ser a base dos trabalhos e provar que o conceito funciona, é o EclipseLink.

Ao utilizar o `Session` diretamente, você está amarrando o seu projeto ao Hibernate. Ou seja, não poderá mudar o implementador do JPA. Porém, raramente você desejaria mudar o implementador do JPA, então raramente isso causa algum problema real.

Essas implementações do JPA estão concorrendo de forma agressiva entre si por desempenho principalmente, e muitas delas alegam bater o Hibernate de longe em diversos benchmarks. Assim sendo, é possível que o seu desempenho fique melhor ao trocar a implementação do JPA por alguma outra, mas se você usar o `Session` diretamente, não poderá fazer essa troca. Por outro lado, na maioria dos casos, os gargalos de desempenho estão em outros lugares.

Há algumas características que o Hibernate oferece por fora do JPA. Ao utilizar-se o Hibernate (não apenas o `Session`) diretamente, você poderá utilizá-las. Obviamente, esses recursos extras não estarão disponíveis em outras implementações do JPA, ao menos não por meio da interface padronizada que o JPA oferece.

Comment: Muito grato pelos esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, JPA é uma especificação.
Hibernate é uma das implementações da JPA, ou seja, implementa a especificação. Assim como EclipseLink, TopLink e OpenJPA.

Pra você gerenciar os seus objetos com JPA você utiliza o **EntityManager**(Especificação) mas caso você queira utilizar o **Hibernate** puro, sem a **JPA**, você vai utilizar **Session** (Implementação). Isso depende da afinidade com implementação, necessidade de uso no contexto do projeto, enfim... 
O fato é que para ter uma aplicação que suporte mudanças de implementações, de **Hibernate** para **EclipseLink** por exemplo, terás que adotar a especificação da **JPA**, ou seja, o **EntityManager**.